# Is it necessary to send a "thank you" email to reseach commitee after on-campus interview?

Tags: tenure-track, interview

I have made a campus interview. I want to send a "thank you" email to research committee. Is it make sense to do ?

Comment: Do you mean the committee responsible for reviewing applications and arranging interviews?  That's usually called the "search committee", not "research".

Comment: I've seen this done multiple time. It's not a game-changer, in my opinion, but is not rude either, so, in doubt, you can just go ahead and do it. As Noah writes, keep it short, though, and don't expect an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've carried out interviews in the library world as well as in the humanities, and I would say that at least in our context (Canada), a quick thank you note is appreciated. You should send these notes to everybody with whom you had a meaningful interaction - i.e. not random faculty in your job talk, but anybody you had a one-on-one interview conversation or a meal with.

Alternatively, you could send an e-mail to the search committee chair. In my experience, they will forward this e-mail to the rest of the committee.

The lack of a thank-you note isn't a deal-breaker, of course, and your committee will hopefully be aware that this is one of those culturally-specific things that not all people know they should do. *But* at least in Canada, you should send thank you notes.

Comment: Does this apply for phone interviews with a group especially if you had no prior communication?

Comment: For a phone interview I would just thank the chair of the committee, but perhaps ask them to convey your thanks to the committee for a thoughtful and enjoyable discussion (or something along those lines).

Answer (score 3):

In my experience this is somewhat uncommon, but not unheard of.  When a candidate did thank everyone they met with it made a positive impression on me and at least some other faculty I talked to.  So if you'd like to send such a note I'd say go ahead and do so, but you should not feel obligated.  I'd suggest you keep the note very short though and not say anything weird.